# HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found (.Net 4)

Tags: iis

I've just got a new server setup on Windows 2008 Web edition. I'm trying to set the first asp.net 4 application up on it but am having nothing but problems.

The latest is that I'm getting the 404.17 error, which says "the requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.".

I've done a lot of research on google but most suggestions seem to be to run aspnet_regiis -i to install asp.net 4. I've done this several times both on the Framework and Framework64 folders, but with no success.

I tried changing from the default application pool to a .net4 application pool, which appeared  to work at first and I instead got a server error to do with permissions. I fixed that, and immediately the 404.17 error returned.

Other suggestions I've read say to go into the "turn windows features on and off" and make sure .net 4 is selected there under IIS. However on this server clicking "turn windows features on and off" takes me to the standard windows 2008 server manager. I click "add features" there, and only ".NET Framework 3.0 Features (Installed)" is listed and selected. .NET 4 isn't shown there, yet it is selectable through the application pools.

What else can I try to get the website running as I'm at a complete loss now. Its annoying because my old server was easy to manage - I did it all through the server itself without a control panel (Windows 2003), now on my new server I have to manage most of it through Plesk because there is no dns.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE:

I have just tried temporarily changing the website to the application pool used by the Plesk control panel, and again got the 500 permissions error. I gave the application pool user read and write permissions to the website folder, and it went back to the 404.17 error. Not sure if this additional info changes anything?

Answer (score 3):

I too had the same problem but solved it with simple solution.   My program was in framework 4.0 but in application pool was mapped to framework 2.0. 
Just changed the frame work in application pool to 4.0. 
It worked.

Answer (score 2):

I've finally figured out the problem, and it was to do with Plesk itself.

After delving through some of the thousands of links throughout the plesk control panel I found a page for "Website Scripting and Security". Under there it was set to .NET 2.0. However, even though I'd installed .NET 4 on the server, Plesk didn't know about it. Although the application pool I'd set the website to run under through IIS was .NET 4, it still wouldn't work for some reason.

I then found another page under "tools and settings" for server components, and on that page is a refresh button. Hit that and it suddenly realised that .NET 4 was installed, went back to the website scripting and security page, selected .NET 4, and hey presto, I got a server error (never have I been so glad to see a server error).

I then just had to give the application pool identity read access to the web folder, and the website worked.

I wish I'd paid an extra £15 per month for Windows 2008 Standard edition now so I could manage it all manually without Plesk.

Comment: I was having the same issue when migrating an Umbraco 7.0 install from my local machine to the production server - this update in Please worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are running this application under a Virtual Directory, also ensure that your IIS has ASP, ASP.Net, ISAPI Extensions And Filters, Static Content installed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

How do I install those extensions and filters? I've tried running some command line commands taken from various websites but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I usually do the add and remove features, in program and features in control panel. 
Here is an example on how to install .Net 3.5 google this and you can find ways to install the other features

DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:d:\sources\sxs

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately the program and features option on my server isn't very helpful, it doesn't seem to go to the usual dialog. The dialog it did open is limited as to what is included. 

I have however now found the solution and have posted it on this page - it appears Plesk rules the server and makes everything ignore IIS settings.

It's the first time I've used plesk (I'm used to doing all the dns / iis stuff manually), so am still getting used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `.net` framework from 'plesk' panel:

- go to Domains
- select then domain
- Go to 'Domain and Websites & Domains'
- Hide Advanced Operations
- Go to 'Asp.net Settings'
- Go to 'Change Version'
- select `4.0`

If you don't have the 4.0 option then you must install the framework on your server first.